# mysql select query result wrong with COUNT(*) and *

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

In Mysql I have count total record for pagination with the help of COUNT(*) aggregate function and for displaying data purpose I am using * instead of COUNT(*) But I got the different total count and return number of row.

query 1:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  change_request
INNER JOIN task_main_management ON cr_project_id = project_id
LEFT JOIN all_module AS am
ON
  am.m_id = task_m_id
WHERE
  cr_tenent_id = '100' AND cr_entity_id = '100' AND cr_project_id = 'PROJ_310820200746367254' AND cr_type = '2' AND change_request.cr_id = '16' AND task_main_management.cr_id = 'CHRQ_020920200807413904'
GROUP BY
  change_request.cr_project_id
```

It has return result  2.

But when I used  * instead of COUNT(*) into the select It has given me single row.

Comment: Share query and result with and without count

Comment: I doubt something like `select * from ... group by change_request.cr_projectid` works

Comment: @jainvikram444  query same which has mentioned in question. Changes has select field only `*` and `count(*)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.. given

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+------+--------------------+------------+------------+----------+
| id   | venue              | city       | date       | time     |
+------+--------------------+------------+------------+----------+
|    1 | Waldorf Hotel      | London     | 2020-01-01 | 07:00:00 |
|    2 | Waldorf Hotel      | London     | 2020-01-02 | 07:00:00 |
|    3 | Heathrow           | London     | 2020-01-02 | 14:00:00 |
|    4 | Lennon Airport     | Liverpool  | 2020-01-02 | 16:00:00 |
|    5 | Port of Liverpool  | Liverpool  | 2020-01-02 | 19:30:00 |
|    6 | Port of Liverpool  | Liverpool  | 2020-01-03 | 07:00:00 |
|    7 | Port of Liverpool  | Liverpool  | 2020-01-04 | 07:00:00 |
|    8 | Port of Liverpool  | Liverpool  | 2020-01-05 | 07:00:00 |
|    9 | Port of Liverpool  | Liverpool  | 2020-01-06 | 07:00:00 |
|   10 | Manchester Airport | Manchester | 2020-01-06 | 12:40:00 |
|   11 | Heathrow           | London     | 2020-01-06 | 14:40:00 |
+------+--------------------+------------+------------+----------+
11 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T WHERE CITY = 'LONDON' GROUP BY CITY;
+------+---------------+--------+------------+----------+
| id   | venue         | city   | date       | time     |
+------+---------------+--------+------------+----------+
|    1 | Waldorf Hotel | London | 2020-01-01 | 07:00:00 |
+------+---------------+--------+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT COUNT(*)
    -> FROM T
    -> WHERE CITY = 'LONDON'
    -> GROUP BY CITY;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        4 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

A group by without an aggregate function will return 1 row of non-determinate values
a group by with an aggregate function but no column to aggregate on will return a count for the rows filtered by the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a `GROUP BY`.  So, the `COUNT(*)` is the value in the *one* row returned.  It would be clearer if the aggregation query used:

```
SELECT change_request.cr_project_id, COUNT(*)
```

With the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT *`, the query is malformed and should return a syntax error.  Unfortunately, older versions of MySQL allow that broken syntax.

I'm not sure what you really want, but you might simply want to remove the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `COUNT(*)`  result is 2 but `*` return single row.

Comment: @Vickysw . . . You are missing the point.  The "2" is in a single row generated by the `GROUP BY`.  You need to remove the `GROUP BY` if you want to see all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many records the resultset will contain, then remove the `group by` clause and use `count(distinct ...)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT  change_request.cr_project_id) cnt
FROM change_request
INNER JOIN task_main_management ON cr_project_id = project_id
LEFT JOIN all_module AS am ON am.m_id = task_m_id
WHERE
  cr_tenent_id = '100' 
  AND cr_entity_id = '100' 
  AND cr_project_id = 'PROJ_310820200746367254' 
  AND cr_type = '2' 
  AND change_request.cr_id = '16' 
  AND task_main_management.cr_id = 'CHRQ_020920200807413904'
```

Note that, for your current `group by` clause, using `select *` is broken. You should be enumerating the columns in the `SELECT` clause, and possibly use aggregate functions on anything that does not come from table `change_request`.

Comment: Thanks for response. I understood your thoughts But for the total number of count is my common function in my structure..  Is there any other way to using `*` getting correct result?